# Claim: The complex conjugate of $ \omega_N $

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

My textbook says that $ \omega^{N-k}_N = \bar \omega^k _N $, where the bar denotes the complex conjugate. Why is this true?

Sidenote: I believe $\omega^{N-k}_N=(e^{-2\pi i}/N)^{N-k} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $\omega_N^k$ (which is never zero) and check that you have an identity. (Note that $z \overline{z} = |z|^2$.)

Without knowing that this is what you should prove, you can divide both sides of the trivial equation $1=1$ by $\omega_N^k$. On the one hand, since it has modulus $1$, this is just the conjugate. On the other hand, since $\omega_N^N=1$, this is $\omega_N^{N-k}$.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't think of this. what do you mean by check that you have an identity?

Comment: @user1961722 The resulting equation is just $1=1$, which is a trivial identity.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to say that the conjugate of $\omega^k_N $ is $1/\omega^k_N $?

Comment: @user1961722 Yep; $1/z=\frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}=\overline{z}$ here, because $|z|=1$ on the circle.

Comment: okay thanks Ian